# Timing issue with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

The code below demonstrates the issue I am having.

When the the js executes, the progress bar fills, as expected rapidly until the max has been reached.

However, the span#pbarval container is updated very slowly and completes LONG after the progress bar has finished.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max= 20000,
        cur=0;
    function updatePBar(){
        cur++;
        jQuery("#pbar").val(cur);
        jQuery("#pbarval").html("" + Math.ceil(cur*100/max) + "%");
        if (cur<=max){
            setTimeout(updatePBar, 10);
        }
    }
    updatePBar();
});
```

You can see the code executing here: http://jsfiddle.net/EricBrian/fhtp6rpf/

Can somebody explain why this is? How to make it keep up with the progress bar?

Also, I noticed that if I switch tabs, the setTimeout seems to pause. The percentage does not update until I switch back to the tab it is running in.

Thanks!
-e

Comment: you are dividing by `max`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `cur` for the value of the progress bar, so the progress bar is full when `cur === 100`, but you're displaying `cur*100/max` as the percentage which doesn't reach `100%` until `cur == 20000`.

You should use the same formula `cur*100/max` for both, and since you want the quick speed you should also divide your max by 100:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/fhtp6rpf/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max= 200,
        cur=0;
    function updatePBar(){
        cur++;
        jQuery("#pbar").val(cur*100/max);
        jQuery("#pbarval").html("" + Math.ceil(cur*100/max) + "%");
        if (cur<max){
            setTimeout(updatePBar, 10);
        }
    }
    updatePBar();
});
```

I also changed the test `cur<=max` to `cur<max` since you probably do not mean to increment `cur` an extra time when it is already at `max`.

Answer (score 2):

Your progress bar max is 100 but your javascript variable max is 2000.

As such, the progress bar fills much quicker because it reaches it right away.

This particular expression is the one guilty for it:

```
Math.ceil(cur*100/max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like below expression is taking too long.

```
Math.ceil(cur*100/max)
```

Simply replace that expression with

```
cur
```

and see how it flies.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to part of your question.  setTimeout is designed to be active when the tab is active. So the behavior regarding the progress bar not being updated when the tab is no active is normal.  You can over come this using this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome).

Comment: `Also, I noticed that if I switch tabs, the setTimeout seems to pause. The percentage does not update until I switch back to the tab it is running in.`

Answer (score 1):

It's just wrong at your `cur`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var max= 20000,
         cur=0;

     function updatePBar(){
         cur++;
         var value = Math.ceil((cur/max) * 100);
         jQuery("#pbar").val(value);
         console.log(cur)
         jQuery("#pbarval").html("" + value + "%");
         if (cur<=max){
             setTimeout(function(){updatePBar();}, 10);
         }
     }
     updatePBar();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning different value to the value of the progress and to the percentage.

Just reuse the same value:

```js
var max = 20000,
    cur = 0;
(function updatePBar() {
  pbarval.innerHTML = (pbar.value = Math.ceil(++cur * 100 / max)) + "%";
  if (cur < max) setTimeout(updatePBar, 10);
})();
```

```html
<progress id="pbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<span id="pbarval"></span>
```

Comment: Note I skipped `var pbarval = document.getElementById('pbarval'), pbar = document.getElementById('pbar');` for simplicity. This is standard but bad practice. Don't skip it in production code.